# Kinetic Js canvas video with javascript

Tags: javascript, video, canvas, kineticjs

Can anyone show me an example of the code used to place video on a canvas with javascript. I just need a video that loops, with a play/stop button. Thanks.

Comment: You can use Kinetic.Shape or Kinetic.Image+multiple image changes to accomplish your task. But these are less efficient than @Yojin's answer which uses a video element (placed to your desired position on the Kinetic.Stage with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas tag and KineticJs lib aren't make to place a video (you can always set each frame, but this is quite dirty, however you can see example here : [javascript video canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186463/javascript-video-canvas?rq=1)).

Better use the html5 video tag instead. You can see all that you need for this here :

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp